# Vuetify - 'Receiving Unknown Custom Element' Error for some Vuetify Components, but not all

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Receiving the error:

> Unknown custom element: `<v-card>` - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Also receiving errors for other components (i.e. v-text-field), however some elements are fine  (v-content, v-spacer, vtoolbar).

In my main.js I have:

```
import { 
 Vuetify,// required 
 VApp, // required 
 VCard,
 VNavigationDrawer, 
 VFooter, 
 VToolbar, 
 VTextField, 
 transitions } 
from 'vuetify' 

Vue.use(Vuetify, 
{ components: { VApp, 
VNavigationDrawer, 
VCard,
VFooter, 
VToolbar, 
transitions, 
VTextField },});  

new Vue({ 
 router, 
 store, 
 render: h => h(App), 
 template: '<App/>', 
 components: { App } 
}).$mount('#app')
```

Please advise what I am missing.  Thank you.

Comment: How are you including vuetify in your project? Via `npm install` or `vue add`?

Comment: Are you using the transform-imports package? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/guides/a-la-carte#importing-components

Comment: I installed Vuetify with' Vue add Vuetify'.  The transform-imports package is installed.  I tried to add the following into the .babelrc, however it appeared to have no effect:  
    "vuetify": [{
      "transform": "vuetify/es5/components/${member}",
      "preventFullImport": true}
    ]